# How to make an executable that browsers won't flag as unsafe?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, security, browser

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to write programs in C++.  They are harmless and small.  When I compile an executable and try hosting it for others to download however, browsers will flag the executable file as "hazardous" and panic people while hiding the option to download or run the file.

What can I do to have my executable be regarded as safe by browsers?

Comment: People downloading your exe (or any other potentially unsafe content) would need to disable that option in their browsers.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't, and that's the point of a browser and OS giving such warnings.   The person downloading your programs - or the person administering their system - CAN make that call but you need to convince them to do so.   There are plenty of legitimate ways to provide that person information to make an informed decision.   Trying to circumvent such decision making (whether through technical or social-engineering means) would, in itself, be viewed with suspicion by even moderately informed people - simply because distributors of malware try to do exactly that.

Comment: Sorry but this question reveals a serious lack of understanding the security threats that everyone should be prepared for. Now, tell me, what if someone hacks your hosting provider and replaces your harmless files with a virus or something different?

Comment: @Peter - Many installers and executables I download online don't elicit the same reaction from the browser though.  If it were a warning all executables were given, it wouldn't be a problem I think, but the warning is totally novel and unexpected, making it appear like the browser seen something special about mine.  They are clearly doing something I'm not to avoid being flagged, and I would like to join them.

Comment: Those installers and executables you downloaded likely are digitally signed.

Comment: @Steve - I am well aware, the problem isn't the warning that all executables get.  It's that browsers flag my executable especially and make employing it opaque/unrecommended from a UX perspective.  They do not treat executables this way usually.

Comment: You need to look into digitally signing your applications.   That normally starts by convincing some trusted authority to provide a digital certificate that can be used to sign your applications i.e. convincing them that YOU are trustworthy.   It also relies on certificates they issue continuing to be trusted (e.g. if too many applications signed using certificates from a particular trusted authority turn out to be untrustworthy, their authority to issue certificates may be revoked).    You might also try submitting your programs to a relevant app store (and go through their QA processes).

Comment: @Peter - Signing services are surprisingly expensive!  I suppose it's to be, but I'll just have to settle for signing them with my own certificate (I assume it provides the same tampering security, whatever that might be, just without the 3rd party vouching for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand why the Portable Executable is being flagged as potentially "unsafe" or "malicious" before you can prevent the continuation of the flag.

Here are some potential reasons.

1. Your website is not signed with a HTTPS certificate which is standard for security in 2018, HTTPS is much safer than HTTP and thus tends to be trusted more often
2. Your website has been flagged by a security team working at the browser vendor / reported by a third-party individual anonymously
3. The Portable Executable is flagged at https://www.virustotal.com/ or an alike service. Google own VirusTotal so they are bound to be using their own service for security purposes on their own web-browser product (e.g. Google Chrome). Microsoft have their own intelligence from data collection and cloud network support with Windows Defender as well. I suspect that APIs from places like PhishTank and alike services are used by some browser vendors as well, as an estimation
4. The browser performed a scan of the Portable Executable after the download and then blocked it after it was about to complete because it internally flagged a finding to be suspicious/awkward in a negative way

There could be another 1000 reasons. I cannot verify if any of the above is guaranteed to be a potential cause because I do not work for the browser vendor you're having issues with however it's a start.

Do you happen to be using a packer, obfuscation, or the alike? This could also be a cause depending on VirusTotal AV scanners and if any internal scan algorithms are included in browser for the end-user downloaded content.

Believe it or not, it could be to do with low-usage... File reputation scanning. SmartScreen flags lesser-known downloads and Google Chrome also does this AFAIK; this is actually a positive thing though because a lot of new malware in the wild will not be heavily exposed at the time of being pushed out and thus less people may become infected assuming they don't simply and blatantly ignore the alert, so I'm all for file reputation scanning.